# Why do i always get this error whenever i use forge test?

Tags: test, foundry, forge

I am trying to use foundry, whenever I use forge test on my mac(10.15.7 Catalina)it throws this error and doesn't install forge-std lib for me.

please how do i resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

can it be that you have other 'forge' cli installed?, my help looks different:

```
javiermac@Donosos-MacBook-Pro spool-foundry % forge help
Build, test, fuzz, debug and deploy Solidity contracts.

Usage: forge <COMMAND>

Commands:
  bind               Generate Rust bindings for smart contracts.
  build              Build the project's smart contracts. [aliases: b]
  cache              Manage the Foundry cache.
  clean              Remove the build artifacts and cache directories. [aliases: cl]
  completions        Generate shell completions script. [aliases: com]
  config             Display the current config. [aliases: co]
  coverage           Generate coverage reports.
  create             Deploy a smart contract. [aliases: c]
  debug              Debugs a single smart contract as a script. [aliases: d]
  flatten            Flatten a source file and all of its imports into one file. [aliases: f]
  fmt                Formats Solidity source files.
  geiger             Detects usage of unsafe cheat codes in a foundry project and its dependencies.
  generate-fig-spec  Generate Fig autocompletion spec. [aliases: fig]
  help               Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)
  init               Create a new Forge project.
  inspect            Get specialized information about a smart contract. [aliases: in]
  install            Install one or multiple dependencies. [aliases: i]
  remappings         Get the automatically inferred remappings for the project. [aliases: re]
  remove             Remove one or multiple dependencies. [aliases: rm]
  script             Run a smart contract as a script, building transactions that can be sent onchain.
  snapshot           Create a snapshot of each test's gas usage. [aliases: s]
  test               Run the project's tests. [aliases: t]
  tree               Display a tree visualization of the project's dependency graph. [aliases: tr]
  update             Update one or multiple dependencies. [aliases: u]
  upload-selectors   Uploads abi of given contract to https://sig.eth.samczsun.com function selector database. [aliases:
                         up]
  verify-check       Check verification status on Etherscan. [aliases: vc]
  verify-contract    Verify smart contracts on Etherscan. [aliases: v]

Options:
  -h, --help     Print help information
  -V, --version  Print version information
```